# Using devise-async gem with RSpec

Tags: rspec, devise, resque

I am using the devise-async gem to send my devise emails asynchronously - using Resque.

I am doing some simple RSpec controller tests to make sure the, say, forgotten password is being sent, by inspecting the ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.

This used to work before I started using the devise-async gem. How can I "send" the emails on the queue immediately, so that they end up in ActionMailer::Base.deliveries?

For example - when I used delayed_job to send them asynchronously (not using the devise-async gem), I could add this to my devise initializer:

```
Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !Rails.env.test?
```

Which would deliver emails straight away to make it easier to test. So - is there a similar technique I can use when using devise-async?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I have found the answer:

In an initializer file, do the following:

```
Resque::Mailer.excluded_environments = [:test]
```

For general Resque jobs, add the following:

```
Resque.inline = Rails.env.test?
```

Answer (score 3):

I put the following line in spec_helper.rb:

```
Devise::Async.enabled = false
```

and it worked.

Comment: Great. This fixed my my service's spec examples asserting `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count` increase when a new confirmable user is created in the DB. The specs were passing before I introduced Devise-Async but afterwards those started failing.This config restored the failing spec examples.